# Why are all my ActionListener's added to JButtons in a loop identical?

Tags: java, swing

Ok so I am trying to make a chess game in swing. I have a program that creates a 2d array of JButton's 8x8. I then create them all in a loop doing stuff like going back and forth between white/black and adding an action event. The problem i am having is that each button has the same action event and it is the event that is created last I.E. button on Row 8 column H is the action listener for all of the buttons in the array. Here is a snippet of code that is where I am creating the buttons and adding them.

I also have an Enum Columns that just goes from int to character 1 to H for example. selectPosition and targetPosition are objects that have two members columns and rows.

```
public void initializeGui(boolean isWhite) {
    boolean shouldBeWhite = true;
    for(int i = 0; i< 8; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            column = i+1;
            row = j+1;
            JButton square = new JButton();
            square.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                            @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    final int thisRow = row;
                                    final int thisColumn = column;
                                    selectPosition.setColumn(Columns.getColumnsFromInt(thisColumn));
                                    selectPosition.setRow(thisRow);
                                    if(isSelecting){
                                        System.out.print("Selecting square to move. Row: " + thisRow + " Column: " +  Columns.getColumnsFromInt(thisColumn));
                                        selectPosition.setColumn(Columns.getColumnsFromInt(thisColumn));
                                        selectPosition.setRow(thisRow);
                                    } else{
                                        System.out.print("Targeting square to move to. Row: " + thisRow + " Column: " + Columns.getColumnsFromInt(thisColumn) + "\n");
                                        targetPosition.setColumn(Columns.getColumnsFromInt(thisColumn));
                                        targetPosition.setRow(thisRow);
                                    }
                                    System.out.println("");
                                isSelecting = !isSelecting;

                                }

            });
            if(shouldBeWhite){
                square.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                shouldBeWhite = false;
            }else{
                square.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                shouldBeWhite = true;
            }
            if (j == 7){
                shouldBeWhite = !shouldBeWhite;
            }
            chessBoardSquares[i][j] = square;
            gui.add(chessBoardSquares[i][j]);
        }
    }
    if(isWhite){
        setInitialPiecesWhiteStart();
    }else{
        setInitialPiecesBlackStart();
    }

}
```

Further up as a member of this class are the following:

```
int column = 0, row = 0;
```

When I click on any of these buttons i see printed

```
Selecting square to move. Row: 8 Column: H
Targeting square to move to. Row: 8 Column: H

Selecting square to move. Row: 8 Column: H
Targeting square to move to. Row: 8 Column: H
```

and so on. My question is why are these buttons all given the same action event? My logic walk through would be something like create the first button set column = i+1 and row = j+1 then add an action listener with an action event that sets the current row/column values to the inner final variables and then prints out the thisRow and thisColumn associated with that action event. Am i overriding the values at the end or do i have the scope wrong? Basically how am i creating these buttons actions listeners incorrectly?

Comment: Because that's the value of `column` and `row` when the `ActionListener` is called. What you need to do is pass the values to the instance of the listener when it's created. I'd take a look at the `Action` API personally

Comment: Ah that makes a bit more sense, as far as passing the values to the instance, aren't i instantiating my new ActionListener and then setting thisRow and thisColumn values? is it like the final value of thisRow and thisColumn are equal to 8 and H so thats what every button returns? If so could you give me an example of how i can  pass the values to an instantiated new ActionListener?

Comment: Also why is my post being downvoted, is it not an acceptable question?

Comment: It's been downvote, possibly because, 10 minutes with a debugger probably would have highlighted the issue, and I'm pretty sure I've seen any number of similar questions, and some people are just grumpy old developers :P

Comment: Haha fair enough. I don't think it's a question that is easily answered without asking for help though because it's like logic that doesn't jump out to you. If i was looking at this code without ever seeing it i would have assumed that yeah that each button would have their own instantiated action listener stored in memory and would all have different values for row and columns and would have those called on click.. weird that it doesnt haha

Comment: Welcome to the forest, look out for the trees ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You could...

Use the `actionCommand` API to pass information between the button and the `ActionListener`...

```
JButton btn = new JButton();
btn.setActionCommand(row + "x" + column);
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
        //...
    }
});
```

The problem here is you're relying on `String` parsing to extract the values, which can get messy quickly

## You could...

Create a custom `ActionListener` which takes the values you want to use...

```
public class SquareActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private int column;
    private int row;

    public SquareActionListener(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This de-couples the `ActionListener` from the rest of the code and provides you the information you need, although, you may need to pass additional information (such as the model) as well for it to work

## You could...

Make use of the `Action` API which is designed to be provide self contained units of work, it's generally a more re-usable solution, but might be a little beyond what you need right now

```
public class SquareAction extends AbstractAction {
    private int column;
    private int row;

    public SquareAction(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This looks alot like the last suggestion, but instead of adding it as the button's `ActionListener`, you actually apply it to the button directly...

```
JButton btn = new JButton(new SquareAction(row, column));
```

The button then uses other properties (which I've not set) to set itself up

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when making a tic-tac-toe game.  I used each button's hashcode to trace back which button was actually pushed.  This is what my button setup looked like:

```
hashcodes= new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i=1;i<=9;i++) {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setHash(button.hashCode());
                testWinner();
                testDraw();
            }
        });
        hashcodes.add(button.hashCode());
        panel.add(button);
    }
}

    private void setHash(int hashcode) {
            for (int h:hashcodes) {
                if (h==hashcode) {
                    //do stuff
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Simpler solutions might include, making a custom `ActionListener` which took the x/y position; Using the `Action` API; using the `actionCommand` to pass information from the button to the `ActionEvent`; using the `clientProperty` of the button itself ... basically a list of things would be more viable then what you've ended up with

Comment: I tried making a custom ActionListener class which worked but then I ended up with this weird scenario where I couldnt easily pass values back to an object outside of the class that I originally created the buttons in. I tried something like ActionListener(int column, int row, Object) and passing in this as a paramter but then I couldn't easily alter that object in the new class outside of the constructor that i called it on

Comment: This is where something like a MVC is useful

Answer (score 0):

This is my Test class, and it works perfectly.

```
public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private javax.swing.JButton[][] buttons;

    private final int ROW = 8;
    private final int COLUMN = 8;

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setExtendedState(javax.swing.JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.buttons = new javax.swing.JButton[ROW][COLUMN];
        this.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(ROW, COLUMN));
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
                final int row = i;
                final int column = j;
                buttons[i][j] = new javax.swing.JButton(
                        String.format("Button %d-%d", i, j));
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    //    System.out.println(
                    //            String.format("You have just pressed the button at row %d and column %d", row, column));
                        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                                Test.this, String.format("You have just pressed the button at row %d and column %d", row, column));
                    }
                });
                this.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```